# Generic Dictionary Comparison

Tags: c#, generics

I have a problem I can't seem to wrap my head around.  I am creating a class to hold a dictionary of items that have generic types.  The problem I'm faced with is needed to force this dictionary to be `InvariantCultureIgnoreCase` *if* the index type is a string.

For example:

```
public class Cache<TIndex, TItem>
{
    protected IDictionary<TIndex, TItem> _cache { get; set; }

    public Cache()
    {
        this._cache = new Dictionary<TIndex, TItem>();
    }

    public bool Exists(TIndex index)
    {
        if (!_cache.ContainsKey(index))
        {
            //....do other stuff here
            this._cache.Add(databaseResult.Key, databaseResult.Value);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

So the first problem was dealing with strings that had various capitalization; I solved this by forcing the data to be upper-case.  Now, however, I've found that there are some characters which are culture specific, so without the invariant culture switch, `ContainsKey` will return false.

I've tried creating a new `IEqualityComparer`, but that never gets fired.  Any ideas?

Comment: The code you've shown doesn't show anything about `IEqualityComparer`. I suspect you really just need to allow an `IEqualityComparer<TIndex>` to be passed into the constructor, and provided to the dictionary.

Comment: "I've tried creating a new IEquityComparer, but that never gets fired." Did you just create it? Or did you actually assign it to the dictionary?

Comment: I've tried this previously; I've assigned it in the constructor but it never fires.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please try the following:

```
public Cache()
{
    if (typeof(TIndex) == typeof(string))
    {
        this._cache = new Dictionary<TIndex, TItem>((IEqualityComparer<TIndex>)StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
    }
    else
    {
        this._cache = new Dictionary<TIndex, TItem>();
    }
}
```

Or (with ternary operator):

```
public Cache()
{
    this._cache = typeof(TIndex) == typeof(string)
                ? new Dictionary<TIndex, TItem>((IEqualityComparer<TIndex>)StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
                : new Dictionary<TIndex, TItem>();
}
```

Or (really short, as suggested by @Rawling):

```
public Cache()
{
    this._cache = new Dictionary<TIndex, TItem>(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase as IEqualityComparer<TIndex>);
}
```

Comment: This looks promising.  I'll let you know if this works.

Comment: It was better before the edit to turn it into a ternary expression.

Comment: My first test was to verify that it did ignore case; this does not.  Sadly that means that it's not applying the StringComparer (but it is adding the correct IEqulaityComparer)

Comment: Alternatively if you want *really short code* you can use `this._cache = new Dictionary<TIndex, TItem>(StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase as IEqualityComparer<TIndex>)` :D

Comment: I tried it here and it does ignore case.  Can you post what you have tried?

Comment: This answer uses `CurrentCultureIgnoreCase`, OP may have better luck with what he asked for (`InvariantCultureIgnoreCase`).

Comment: Updated answer to use `InvariantCultureIgnoreCase`. Thanks, @David S.

Comment: It does ignore the case on a new solution.  There's obviously something else further up the chain that is stopping this from happening.  I'm looking into the rest of the solution to see where the problem could lie.

Comment: This solution worked for me (as did @Tim, you were simply first).  My problem was that I was overwriting the internal dictionary later on when I was seeding the cache.  I should have copied the values into the internal dictionary.  However, I do like this solution as it allows me to tweak the culture.  Thanks so much for all of your help!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a fully functional version of what I THINK you're asking for (I had to add a Set function, otherwise it is based on your own code). It is, as the if/Console.WriteLine checks show, ignoring case. If this isn't what you're looking for, please clarify your question further.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Cache<string, string> stringCache = new Cache<string, string>();

        stringCache.Set("A String Index", "A String Item");

        if (stringCache.Exists("A String Index"))
            Console.WriteLine("Title Case exists");

        if (stringCache.Exists("A STRING INDEX"))
            Console.WriteLine("All Caps Exists");

        if (stringCache.Exists("a string index"))
            Console.WriteLine("All Lowercase Exists");
    }
}

class Cache<TIndex, TItem>
{
    private IDictionary<TIndex, TItem> _cache { get; set; }

    public Cache()
    {
        if (typeof(TIndex) == typeof(string))
        {
            _cache = new Dictionary<TIndex, TItem>((IEqualityComparer<TIndex>)StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
        }
        else
        {
            _cache = new Dictionary<TIndex, TItem>();
        }
    }

    public void Set(TIndex index, TItem item)
    {
        _cache[index] = item;
    }

    public bool Exists(TIndex index)
    {
        if (!_cache.ContainsKey(index))
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: This actually gives the results that I expect; however, it doesn't work in my current context for some reason.  I'm debugging to see what's the possible differences.